# Selected tab on TextMate almost un-noticeable

Tags: textmate

[image]

For some reason the selected tab on TextMate is almost un-noticeable, I really cannot make it out, they all look the same to me. When I switch tab I notice it changing color, so I guess it's very very very slightly different, but that doesn't help much.

I've been having this problem for a while, but IIRC it worked fine some times ago — I've no idea what happened to trigger this change.

TextMate 1.5.10, OSX 10.6.8

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your screenshot looks normal to me.

Check your monitor’s “brightness” and “contrast” settings, and possibly your color profile (System Preferences → Displays → Color). On a flat-panel display, there may be a setting which will over-brighten the input signal, causing the top end of the range (light gray to white) to be clipped, so that it is all white (just like overexposure in a camera). There is no good reason to do this ordinarily, especially with a digital input signal, so you should adjust the settings to avoid clipping.

Here’s an image of a black-to-white gradient with a gray border. If a large portion of the left end looks flat white, then you are having that problem.

[image]

Comment: Well, the white portion is more or less 3x-5x larger than the black one, so I guess you're right (I'll leave this open until I can actually try to adjust these settings), thanks.

Comment: (that said, if there's a solution which doesn't involve changing the system settings, and instead configuring something specific, it would be nice)

Comment: This is usually not your OS settings but your monitor's settings. Those settings are **wrong** — they are destroying part of every image you look at (well, every image containing light colors).

Comment: Doing a (software) display calibration fixed this problem, thanks :)